# Iterate on "statics" members

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to iterate on class members defined in a statics block? For example, if I have the following class definition:

```
qx.Class.define("app.MyEnumeration", {
    type: "static",

    statics: {
        ENUM_VALUE_1: 1,
        ENUM_VALUE_2: 2,
        ENUM_VALUE_3: 3
    }
}
```

Can I iterate on those members somehow? Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < app.MyEnumeration.statics.length; i++)
    doSomething(app.MyEnumeration.statics[i]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a specific API, but you can do it easily enough in code by iterating the properties of a class, eg:

```
Object.keys(qx.util.ColorUtil).forEach(function(key) { 
    console.log(key);
});
```

or, using your example:

```
for (var i = 0, arr = Object.keys(app.MyEnumeration); i < arr.length; i++)
    doSomething(app.MyEnumeration[arr[i]])
```